# Facebook share and publish_actions permission

Tags: android, facebook

If we are sharing post using FeedDialogBuilder, do we still need to use publish_actions permission?

Currently, I'm trying to submit a review for my app for publish_actions permission and it keeps on telling me that I have not used a call to the api even though I have already tried to share it on my wall.

I am using an account with an admin role for testing the share function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you don´t need `publish_actions` for Share/Feed Dialogs - but why not just try it without the permission and forget about the Review?

Comment: Just seen the document Feed dialog. Thanks btw :)